# Linux C++ Compile Boost into my program

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I've look around google and StackOverflow but can't seem to ask the right question to get a useful answer.

I have an application program that compiles on Ubuntu 10.04 and links in the Boost::serialization library.  When I tried to run my code on another machine, it won't run saying it can't find the Boost library...

How do I alter my gcc/g++ compile params to tell the compiler to include the Boost libs in my executable?  That is, how do I compile to get a fully transportable program?

Do I need to change anything in my C++ if I do this?

Comment: Have you tried `g++ -static` ?

Comment: No.  Figured it'd look something like that.  But won't this make ALL of my libs static?  Can I just list those I want compiled in while excluding others?

Comment: This is easier with a build system like CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my coworker found this page: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=491455

From that, he found that we have to use these flags: -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_serialization -Wl,-Bdynamic

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've used static linking to compile your app?

Comment: No.  Otherwise it'd be transportable.